# Не изменяется разметка после загрузки на сервер

Tags: html, opencart

Есть сайт на OpenCart. Почему после загрузки на сервер, я не могу изменить html разметку? Т.е. я редактирую файл, он сохраняется, но в браузере ничего не меняется. Пробовал обновлять кэш браузера, модификатор, но ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сбросить не кэш браузера, а кэш OpenCart, попробуй удалить все файлы из `system/cache`, кроме `index.html`, если нет той папки, то посмотри `system/storage/cache`